# Why class's attribute is missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to make set with for my own objects witch can recognize same objects at append and falls them.

```
function ImageSet(){
    this.set = [];
}

ImageSet.prototype.length = function(){return this.set.length}
ImageSet.prototype.process = function(imgObj){
    var is_exist = false;
    $.each(this.set, function(i){
        if (this.set[i].imgHash == imgObj.imgHash){is_exist = true};
    });

    if (!is_exist){
        this.set[this.set.length + 1] = imgObj;
        return true;
    }
    return undefined;
}

var imagesChoosen = new ImageSet();
```

And so when user click on element I create new object and try append it to my ImageSet.
On the first click object successfully append to set, but on second click console write error

```
TypeError: this.set is undefined if (this.set[i].imgHash == imgObj.imgHash){is_exist = true};
```

And code which call ImageSet is:

```
$('#content_table a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    el = new Image($(this).attr('href'));
    if (imagesChoosen.process(el)){
        $(this).parent().css("border", "3px dotted orange");    
    } else {
        $(this).parent().css("border", "None");
    }
    console.log(imagesChoosen.length());
    return false;
});
```

I can't understand. Is my ImageSet is destruct after the first call?

Comment: `this` inside the `$.each` callback is not the same as `this` outside it. Put a `var that = this` before the each, and access `that.set` inside the callback.

Comment: That's what I thought when I looked at it; changing this context from events but why would there be no error the first time? I think the first time it adds an element at this.set[this.set.length **+1**].Adding an element at this.set[1] the next time (where the error occurs) it checks this.set[0] which is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.set[this.set.length + 1] = imgObj;
```

think should be:

```
this.set[this.set.length] = imgObj;
```

I am not familiar with the JQuery each function but previous posts would indicate changing of this context so I would change the for each:

```
$.each(this.set, function(i){
    if (this.set[i].imgHash == imgObj.imgHash){is_exist = true};
});
```

to:

```
for(var i=0;i<this.set.length;i++){
    if (this.set[i].imgHash == imgObj.imgHash){is_exist = true};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the anonymous function you pass to `each`:

```
$.each(this.set, function(i){
    if (this.set[i].imgHash == imgObj.imgHash){is_exist = true};
});
```

… the value of `this` is the member of the array currently being acted on, not `imagesChoosen`.

To access that, you need to copy `this` from the outside function to another variable that remains in scope.

```
var is_exist = false;
var currentImageSet = this;
$.each(this.set, function(i){
    if (currentImageSet.set[i].imgHash == imgObj.imgHash){is_exist = true};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` means current iteration in jquery each which is creating problem with this class keyword; You are treating this like a normal array so I would prefer using for loop!

```
ImageSet.prototype.process = function(imgObj){
    var is_exist = false;
    for(var i=0; i<this.set.length; i++)
    {
        if (this.set[i].imgHash == imgObj.imgHash){is_exist = true};
    }

    if (!is_exist){
        this.set[this.set.length] = imgObj;
        return true;
    }
    return undefined;
}
```